# Based on Model Column Value(true/False) in MVC3 Webgrid , How can Add a Link as column in diplaying the rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3 Webgrid.  I have model which has column of type bool. Based on the value of this column I need to render a column, with hyper link. If the bool column value is true then I have to render Record, else Edit.

Could you kindly give the syntax for these in Razor .

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if statement when you create the column, like so:

```
grid.Column("Conditional Cell Sample", format: @<text>@if(true == true) { @Html.ActionLink("Go here", "Home") } else { @Html.ActionLink("Or here", "Away") }</text>)
```

Simply replace true == true with your condition, and the content of if and else to be what you need.

Ref: http://lottemae.wordpress.com/2011/11/17/using-conditional-statements-in-an-mvc-3-webgrid-column-using-razor/